# How to test failed transactions with the PayPal JS SDK

Tags: paypal

We are using the PayPal JS SDK ^5.1.0 and I'm using it to generate a pay button like described in the docs:

```js
const paypal = await loadScript({
     "client-id": conf.client_id,
     "currency": conf.currency_code
});

await paypal.Buttons({
    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: (coData, actions) => {
        if (price.getTotal()) {

            data.data.amount = price.getTotal();

            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    description: config.registrationCenterDisplayName,
                    amount: {
                        value: price.getTotal().toFixed(2) // Can also reference a variable or function
                    },
                }],
                application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
                }
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error('Amount can not be 0');
        }
    },
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: (oaData, actions) => {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];

            data.data.id = transaction.id;
            data.data.status = transaction.status;

            dataValid = true;

            submit();
        });
    }
}).render(buttonWrapper[0]);
```

It seems not to work well with error case i live. How can I provoke failed transactions or capture erros in sandbox mode?

I found the [negative testing mode](https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/error-conditions/#link-enablenegativetesting) of a sandbox, but it does not change the behaviour for the button. I still get only positive responses.

I opened also an issue in the github repo: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-js/issues/273

Thx a lot for any help! I might overlook something very obvious...

Answer (score 0):

For client-side captures, `actions.order.capture().then(` is only triggered when a capture is successful.

Failure cases are handled by the JS SDK itself, there is no need to test anything as it is not your code.

---

For server-side capturing (not your question) and using the JS SDK for approval, see [the demo code here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server). Negative testing can be used from server API calls for failures if desired.

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX, thx a lot for answer. So what kind of result will I get for a failed client-side capture? I know it's happening, because we got one case on live already.

Comment: No result, an error message is displayed, likely with a try again or return to merchant button.